# CSS Scrollbar including webpage padding

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone as you can see on screenshot container `padding` including scrollbar `width`. When I set `padding-left : 0` to container its going to outside of webpage which means search icon stays under of scrollbar Help me please.

[image]

[code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWEnj.png)

Comment: Can you share your code or any fiddle?

Comment: I edited my post check out please.

Comment: @ÇağrıÖzarpacı Share the code as text or JSfiddle with the problem, retyping your image is very tedious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding values add to the width of your container. So if your container width is set to 1210px with 15px padding on both sides, the rendered width of your container is 1240px. You can subtract the padding values from your width, making it 1180px.